# How do custom domains work with routing, links, and redirects in a Saas app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, multi-tenant, saas, cname

I understand that if I want customers to be able to use a custom domain that points to their space at `customer.mysaasapp.com`, they must define a CNAME record that aliases the canonical `customer.mysaasapp.com` domain.

What I don't understand is how this alias persists across requests. For example, if the customer site links to its resources, how does it know whether to link to the `customer.mysaasapp.com/videos` domain vs the `customclientdomain.com/videos` resource? I don't want the true subdomain to show up in the navigation bar as soon as a link is clicked. How is this handled?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain it for you. As you already know CNAME are canonical names for another domain.

As you know when we hit a domain in browser address bar. Browser asks the DNS (domain name server) where to send the request.  DNS matches the domain name and sends the IP address back to browser and browser hit those IP address to get the response. 
But when we want multiple sites to be served from same IP address which is the case in SAAS app. We can define CNAME for each client. Which is alternative to IP mapping.

So when browser asks the DNS about the address for the provided host url. DNS sends back the actual domain name/path and tell's the browser that it's the right address to ask.

So now browser sends the request to actual domain behind the scene and sets the HOST header to the provided address which user entered. (**customclientdomain.com/videos** for your case).

Now the server knows which host was provided by the user and responds accordingly.

From next request onward Browser does the magic and give you a mimic that it's a totally new website.

All of the modern browser including WGET ,  CURL also handles this.

[Here](http://rossduggan.ie/blog/infrastructure/cnames-how-do-they-work/) is a link with more details.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I understand now. I was under the assumption that DNS concerns were completely separate from web browser concerns. How long does the browser behave like this for? Is it until something breaks the cycle of passing the HOST header back and forth in requests and responses?

Comment: Browser already behaves likes this. Because browser follow the exact same rule. It does require DNS about the address and follow the steps as mentioned. (It can only be done if server explicitly redirect to the new host or user himself enter the other domain). Consider it like 2 separate websites. So browser automatically wont switch the website unless you do it yourself or server of a site sends the browser to another site (like if you are on stackoverflow you wont go to some other site like https://www.suitposh.com automatically)